# Frequent DB connection issues while connecting to mongo DB server

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, graphql, vercel

Frequent error timedout while connecting to mongo DB server

Error message occured-
2023-05-19T01:57:59.725Z    1183f6d2-d935-405c-ade1-3526a80bbedf    ERROR   Error connecting to MongoDB: MongoServerSelectionError: connection timed out
at Timeout._onTimeout (/var/task/node_modules/mongodb/lib/sdam/topology.js:278:38)
at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:569:17)
at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:512:7) {
reason: TopologyDescription {
type: 'ReplicaSetNoPrimary',
servers: Map(3) {
'ac-bnzkcy9-shard-00-00.l3eds49.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription],
'ac-bnzkcy9-shard-00-01.l3eds49.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription],
'ac-bnzkcy9-shard-00-02.l3eds49.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription]
},
stale: false,
compatible: true,
heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
localThresholdMS: 15,
setName: 'atlas-fu1cnm-shard-0',
maxElectionId: null,
maxSetVersion: null,
commonWireVersion: 0,
logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null
},
code: undefined,
[Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(0) {}
}
RequestId: a17c051d-ef52-49b9-aeff-525e5f376e08 Error: Runtime exited with error: exit status 1
Runtime.ExitError

```
const client = new MongoClient(uri, {
    serverApi: {
        version: ServerApiVersion.v1,
        deprecationErrors: true,
    },
    connectTimeoutMS: "10000",
});

try {
    await client.connect();
    db = client.db('Store');

} catch (error) {
    console.error('Error connecting to MongoDB:', error);
    process.exit(1);
}
```

I have deployed nodejs code in vercel and mongo db connection frequently timesout and works only after 5-6 api hits to the deployed api in vercel